# I cant get the armature to move/ parent to the mesh

Tags: armature

I have a model of a skeleton and a full armature but when it parents to the mesh with automatic weights , it says "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones".[image: .]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=bone%20heat

Comment: In this kind of meshes (unless you want the skeleton bones to bend) you shouldn't use automatic weighting, which is optimized for organic deforms. When parenting with Ctrl P use "with empty groups" option instead, then do a manual weight assignement, so that a skeleton bone is assigned to an armature bone only (and so it won't deform).